# Having trouble with Laravel basic auth

Tags: php, laravel-5, postman, basic-authentication

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to use laravel basic auth for android application login. I can login without any problem to my website but using the same username and password in postman basic auth , I got the message "sorry, you are not authorized". I'm completely confused, can anyone help me please?

The basic auth middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as AuthFactory;

class BasicAuth
{

protected $auth;

/**
 * Create a new middleware instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory  $auth
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(AuthFactory $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    return $this->auth->basic('phone') ?: $next($request);
}
```

}

The route that I call in postman is:

```
Route::middleware('basic.auth')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
return $request->user();
});
```

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNlqH.jpg)

Comment: Could you post the code please?

Comment: Also have a look at this: https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/

Comment: @RuanPetersen Petersen which part of code?

Comment: Where you added the authentication. Where did you put the auth functions from postman?

Comment: Did you register your middleware in Kernel.php?

Comment: @RuanPetersen Yes, this code works on localhost without any problem.

Comment: Double check your DB calls, does it reference the same DB and table on your app as it does in the setup of Postman?

Comment: Check this article. It might shed some light on the situation: https://blog.pusher.com/laravel-jwt/

Comment: and this: https://medium.com/@mshanak/laravel-5-token-based-authentication-ae258c12cfea

Comment: @RuanPetersen Thank you for your help, but still not working